# Force download link on a google docs spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-export-url

Is there a way to force a download link instead of the browser trying to open the file? In this case I have a docs spreadsheet and a some links to mp3 files. I want the users to download these files instead of the browser playing it. The mp3's are hosted on another site.
Thanks, Bo

Comment: Gotta love how complicated they're making this. Guess I'll just use another platform instead.

Answer (score 36):

To make download links for documents -
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/Export?docID=yourDocId

To make download links for any file -
https://docs.google.com/uc?id=yourDocId&export=download&hl=en_US

To make download links for spreadsheets -
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=yourDocId&exportFormat=csv

For further information please go [here](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingSpreadsheets)

---

**UPDATING IN 2018**

The new *download URL*  is 
  `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<KEY>/export?gid=<GID>&format=csv`  
where `<KEY>` and `<GID>` can be obtained from your *navigation's URL*, 
  `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<KEY>/edit#gid=<GID>`

PS:  spreadsheets (workbook) may have multiple sheets (worksheets), *GID* is the desired sheet ID. One-sheet-spreadsheet usually has `gid=0`, but if you add more they'll have random numbers (the *GID* is preserved even changing tab-order).

So, using `wget` or `curl` you can test,

```
   wget --no-check-certificate -O test.csv \
    'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/0At2sqNEgxTf3dEt5SXBTemZZM1gzQy1vLVFNRnludHc/export?gid=0&format=csv'
```

Comment: That link for "download links for any file" is broken. Update?

Comment: How would these links look like now?

Comment: It also works if you omit the gid parameter, e.g. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<KEY>/export?format=xlsx

Comment: @Kelvin It doesn't work now, any updates?

Answer (score 5):

To expand on Mokarom's answer (because I can't comment) you need to replace the part of those links that say "yourDocId" with the document id of the page you're trying to download. This is the key= part of the url.

For example, if you had a spreadsheet at [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?**key=0AhjOs40Xk1-4dGg0MjMVYURPMFRpeUFhbmZBTkZ0dEE**#gid=8](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AhjOs40Xk1-4dGg0MjMVYURPMFRpeUFhbmZBTkZ0dEE#gid=8), then you would go to [https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?**key=0AhjOs40Xk1-4dGg0MjMVYURPMFRpeUFhbmZBTkZ0dEE**&exportFormat=csv](https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=0AhjOs40Xk1-4dGg0MjMVYURPMFRpeUFhbmZBTkZ0dEE&exportFormat=csv) for the download link.

Answer (score 0):

In my app I needed to download a Google Drive's spread sheet in the form
of a CSV file (Comma Separated Values).  Google Drive's files are referenced by long ID's such as:

1uFwmwD5UFLdD1DMPGT5p4fIGozfImx44DNCOeMJr1Lo

Here is a code block that will do this.  If there is an error the method will return a zero length string.

```
- (NSString *) downloadGoogleSheetGivenFileID: (NSString *) ID {
// This will download a Google spreadsheet given it's file ID
// and convert it to a CSV file.
NSString    *   preFix;
NSURL       *   myURL;
NSString    *   opCmd;
NSString    *   t;
NSString    *   theStuff;
NSError     *   error = nil;

theStuff = @"";
// The URL has to be: prefix+ID+opCmd  The only thing that changes is the file's ID
preFix = @"https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=";
opCmd = @"&exportFormat=csv";
t = preFix;
t = [t stringByAppendingString:ID];
t = [t stringByAppendingString:opCmd];
myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:t];
theStuff = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:myURL encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if(error != nil)
{
    // There was an error downloading the spread sheet file.
    // We will return a zero length string.
    NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
return theStuff;
```

}

Comment: Add tags to let relevant people know about your question.