# How to R&W to google sheets via url with python

Tags: python, google-sheets, pycharm, chat

I am trying to build a google sheets based chat with python and I'm having trouble understanding how to read&write from the spread sheet on my drive (without using Google API of course, explanation why at the end*)

So far I've gotten to a place where I can get the file, but I cant read the content. Like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import StringIO

orig_url='https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bnCDl1DqRLqO8xHx3sjWdkydYC7rEb3vjpXUZ3ps2tY/edit?usp=sharing'

file_id = orig_url.split('/')[-2]
dwn_url='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + file_id
url = requests.get(dwn_url).text
csv_raw = StringIO(url)
dfs = pd.read_csv(csv_raw)
print(dfs.head())
```

P.S. I looked online for many other resources, from I can tell they are all using google API

*I am building the chat app as part of a course and using API's is not a part of it yet, for that reason I cannot use google API

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the Google api documentation specifically Google sheets API: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api
There you can read about how to enable the sheets api, create authentication tokens and how to use the api calls in your preferred language.

Comment: Hi nir, thanks for ur reply! but as specified the all point is how to do it without google API

Comment: That's a very strange assignment, I have to say. You can try by using the shared link url and parsing the html page to try to find which elements contain the sheet (might not work since Google might use some containers which could not be parsed in such a way). Another option will be to download the file locally and then open that file and try to parse it.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058146/force-download-link-on-a-google-docs-spreadsheet

Comment: Lol is that really? I'll make sure to address ur input forward. I will try using the technique u suggested and download it first, I tried parsing specified elements  but that did not work. hope it works, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Google API, you can try [sheetdb.io](https://sheetdb.io). It's a tool that turns a Google Spreadsheet into a JSON API. So you can use HTTP requests to read and write to a Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: That sounds great! Ill check it out, thank you!